# How do brokerage fees affect the fair market value of a house in a buyout?

Tags: real-estate, fees, home-equity, appraisal

If Alice and Bob buy a house for $100,000, and one of them needs to buy out the other's share soon after, would the fair market value be $100,000 (the purchase price) or $94,000 (what they would get after brokers' fees if they sold it)?

While I understand that prices are generally whatever people can negotiate, assume that Alice and Bob either want to be fair with each other or have a contract requiring one to pay the other the fair market value for their share.

Comment: The fair market value isn't guaranteed to be either one or the other.  It might be both or something else.  The fair market value is not a definite, unique number.

Comment: Depends on who agrees to pay how much of the fees. This is a contract negotiation, not a formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends upon the skill of the negotiator.  In my own case, of such a thing, I received (([fair market price]-[mortgage]) * (.92)) / 2.

The .92 represented what was left over of a 6% real estate commision plus 2% closing costs.  It was fair enough and the other lawyer was a very good negotiator.

To answer your question in a general manner, you typically split the **proceeds** of the sale not necessarily the sale price.  Real estate has especially high transaction costs.  Depending upon market conditions they could be higher than 8% or even 10%.

Comment: Corrected, TY for your math skills.